# Alertdialog pop inside a while statement

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an alert box where a user can enter a persons name presses Ok and the box comes up again if there is another persons name to be entered. The code below does work, but if there is a high number of people to be added (like 50) my tablet crashes and resets. I'm pretty sure this happens because there are 50 dialog boxes drawn on top of each other and my tablet runs out of memory and shuts down.

How can I get it to wait for the user to input the name and then run again?

```
        while(i < number)
        {
            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);
            alert.setMessage("Enter persons name (" + (number - i) + " names left to enter)");
            alert.setView(input);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
                {
                    String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
                    setUp(value);
                }
            });
            alert.show();
            i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are showing all alerts at the same time.

Pseudo code to avoid this problem:

```
function showAlerts(Integer i) {
    if (i < number) {
        // Build the alert and display it
        alert.setPositiveButton(..., new OnClickListener() {
            setup(...);
            showAlerts(i+1);
        }
    }
}

showAlerts(0);
```

Comment: I did have it in an if function, but it only showed the popup once.

Comment: If you look at the rest of the code, I am recursively calling showAlerts to show it 50 times.

Comment: I see it now, I missed it. Thanks a lot :)